# Referencing: non-English material

Tags: discussion

Not everything I claim to know/be true is basic (say, Horowitz/Hill or part's data sheet) or self-invented.
I am aware of the [help on How to reference material written by others](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/help/referencing).

What is the politics (forbidden/deprecated/tolerated/recommended) where the reference material isn't in English?
There is a range from *translation true to the best of one's capabilities* to *interpretation*, in English for this site.
When presenting something as a (block-) quote, striving for the former seems prudent, and identifying originator and source natural.
I don't find it as clear where "just" trying to present an idea with a focus on understandability, but aware of one prominent inspiration.

Triggering this meta-question was a late addition triggered by a comment to my [answer about an LED driver design](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/a/645008), I felt it was off not to mention Eberhard Haug, slept over it, added hyperlink&co - and don't like it any better.
(The answer may be more useful now - [rev. 2](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/revisions/645008/2) was succinct.)

Comment: Can you edit and expand your question, adding some background and context. I'm not sure which angle you're coming at this from or exactly what you're looking for.

Comment: What difference does it make what language the material is written in? Can you give an example of how this might be relevant?

Comment: I'm confused by the question. Do you mean "What is the _policy_...?"

Answer (score 1):

Whatever language the source material is in, it needs a reference in English. The reference for the source can be the same as the example